# Store images into a specified location on local system

Tags: file-io, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am using Play Framework 2.0.4. Here is my code that I have tried :

```java
public static Result save() throws FileNotFoundException {

    Form<Tenant> tenantForm = form(Tenant.class).bindFromRequest();
    Form<Ten> tenForm = form(Ten.class).bindFromRequest();
    Long tenantid = tenForm.get().tenant_id;


    Http.MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    Http.MultipartFormData.FilePart picture = body.getFile("logo_url");

    if (picture != null) {
        String fileName = picture.getFilename();
        String contentType = picture.getContentType();
        File file = picture.getFile();
        tenantForm.get().logo_url = file.getPath();
        tenantForm.get().save();


      return redirect(
           routes.Application.index()
      );
    } else {
        flash("error", "Missing file");
        return redirect(
           routes.Project.ctstenant(0,"name","asc","","",tenantid)
        );
    }
}
```

It will stores the image in temp folder. I want it to store in a specified folder. With the example will be appreciated.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why don't you just move the file from temp to where you want it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can move your file from TEMP folder to your file storage directory. Below is the example how to move your uploaded file :

```java
// define file storage path
public static final String fileStoragePath = "D:\\filestorage\\";

// handle form submit action
public static Result save() {

   // bind request logic
   ...

   if (picture != null) {
      String fileName = picture.getFilename();
      String contentType = picture.getContentType();
      File file = picture.getFile();

      // log message to console
      Logger.info("Original file name = " + fileName + 
         " with Content Type " + contentType);

      // Rename or move the file to the storage directory
      if (file.renameTo(new File(fileStoragePath + fileName))) {
         Logger.info("Success moving file to " + file.getAbsolutePath());
      } else {
         Logger.info("Failed moving file on " + file.getAbsolutePath());
      }

      // save your file name or using blob (it is your choice)
      ...
   }
}
```

---

> Note that, path defined on `fileStoragePath` must be available before to successfully moving or renaming the uploaded file.